# logarithms of dimensional quantities

Tags: logarithms, dimensional-analysis

I know that the argument of transcendental functions must be dimensionless. I am having difficulty understanding, then, how logarithms can be used in general. In some cases, I have seen that the quantity must be nondimensionalized before a logarithm can be applied. This makes sense to me with single terms on the left- and right-hand sides, for instance, $M/M_o$ could be a non-dimensional mass.

But more generally, how is it possible to take the logarithm of products of variables, e.g., $F = ma$? Here, $\log F = \log m + \log a$, or in dimensional units, $\log MLT^{-2}=\log M+\log LT^{-2}$.

This question is motivated by the formulation of [allometry in biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allometry), which is constructed as $y=kx^a$, or in logarithm form, $\log y =\log k + a\log x$. *k* is taken to be a dimensional constant, but because *y* and *x* can have any units, then this violates the nondimensionality of the logarithm. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

Only take the logarithm of dimensionless quantities:

$$\log\frac{F}{ma}=0,$$

$$\log\frac{y}{kx^a}=0.$$

In the second case, $x$ must itself be a dimensionless parameter, otherwise $x^a$ would be meaningless (unless it is a small integer).

---

You can also work with reduced quantities, i.e. use reference values that are known to be compatible: using

$$F_0=m_0a_0,$$

$$\log\frac{F}{F_0}=\log\frac{m}{m_0}+\log\frac{a}{a_0},$$

and

$$y_0=k_0x_0^a,$$

$$\log\frac{y}{y_0}=\log\frac{k}{k_0}+a\log\frac{x}{x_0}.$$

Comment: I had wondered about nondimensionalizing, but assumed that both sides would need to be divided by $F_o$, which would have left the right-hand side with dimensions.  I guess this is not how reduced quantities work? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @noname: I agree with it.

Comment: Ok, I realize that what I am really asking is, does the nondimensionality of the logarithm's argument mean that log(y/y0) =/= log(y) - log(y0)? i.e., the rules of logarithms only apply insofar as they would not introduce dimensions?

Comment: Right, if $y$ has a dimension, $\log y$ is meaningless, just like $sin y$ would be.